# git pull from the cloned remote branch

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh, version-control

Hi i have cloned a remote branch to a different server using

```
sudo ~/gitkey.sh -i ~/.ssh/kan.pem git clone 
     ssh://gitolite3@555.555.55.55:22222/test_adapter -b remote_branch local_folder_server
```

now i have done some changes to the `remote_branch` code from my local machine and committed to the `remote_branch` .

now i want to get my changes on `remote_branch` to my `local_folder_server` .

I tried with

```
sudo ~/gitkey.sh -i ~/.ssh/kan.pem git pull
     ssh://gitolite3@555.555.55.55:22222/test_adapter -b remote_branch local_folder_server
```

and it is not working.

I checked in the internet for some solutions .but does not understand, i am really new to git , please help me to pull my changes .

Thank you .

**UPDATE**

when i go inside my `local_folder_server` and typed `git branch` it will show me `*remote_branch`

Comment: Did you push the branch to the repository after the commit?

Comment: yes i pushed my local changes to the remote_branch . now i want to pull those changes from  local_folder_server . local machine , remote branch and local_folder_server are in 3 places

Comment: So why you just can't do `git pull remote_branch master`? Is your remote branch actuall server or just local repository on that server?

Comment: remote_branch is in a different server .

Comment: what is the output of `git fetch --all`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `git pull` is different from the `git clone` command.
Normally you should be inside a repository directory (`local_folder_server` in your case) to make pull. Also you don't need to use `-b` before branch name.
So execute the following command while you in the `local_folder_server`:

```
sudo ~/gitkey.sh -i ~/.ssh/kan.pem git pull
 ssh://gitolite3@555.555.55.55:22222/test_adapter remote_branch
```

Starting from git 1.8.5 you can tell git to go into some directory before executing a command, using the option `-C <dir_name>`. Will be like that:

```
sudo ~/gitkey.sh -i ~/.ssh/kan.pem git -C local_folder_server pull
 ssh://gitolite3@555.555.55.55:22222/test_adapter remote_branch
```